# How to see output in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, output

I'm new to VS Code. I run simple function in Python and want to see output. I use "Debug" -> "Start Debugging".

```
def double_char_function(string):
string = 'abc'
return_string = ''

for char in string:
    return_string += char*2
return return_string
```

I want to see the output:

aabbcc

I saw it when I run it. But don't know how to see it again. Please, help me to use VS Code.

Screenshots:

1. [Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY5d3.png)
2. [Output is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdxvH.png)

Kind regards,
Anna

Comment: You're never calling your function. You need to call `double_char_function` with a string for it to process, and then `print` out what it returns.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you. I have my function giving me output now

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def double_char_function(string):
    return_string = ''

    for char in string:
        return_string += char*2
    return return_string

print(double_char_function('abc'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solutions provided above, I'd recommend you to learn the basics from a YouTube tutorial (eg. tutorials by CoreyMS, Mosh, etc), since it's always better to learn systematically especially for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you, I checked CoreyMS tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def double_char_function(string):
    return_string = ''

    for char in string:
       return_string += char*2
    
    return return_string
string = "Hello!"
print(double_char_function(string))
```

Comment: This doesn't adds anything extra to @Álvaro Navarro Torres's answer